# Are all the motions of fundamental particles strictly discrete?

Tags: kinematics, spacetime, discrete

I was thinking about how we use the movements of particles in quartz crystals to measure time, using the convenient fact that it undergoes periodic and specific motions. Essentially, its motion has to be quantized for time measurement to be consistent.

Now, since energy is quantized (available only in "packets"), would that necessarily have to imply that all motions along all directions of any fundamental particles can occur in only those amounts that can be represented as a corresponding value of energy spent/obtained?

In the case that motion need actually be quantized, would angular motion need to be quantized too? If a particle is at $x_i, y_i, z_i$ and moving along the direction of the vector ${\bar v}$ at some time $t_i$, then would that render certain angles impossible for it to attain ($\pm\;\alpha$), in any plane $p_j$ such that $\bar v \in p_j$?

If there are any flaws in my understanding of physics, assumptions/premises, or reasoning, please help me understand those too.

Comment: The idea of motion, and a definite trajectory, of any entity, are strictly classical, the words don't have any meaning on the scale you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, since energy is quantized (available only in "packets"),

Energy is a continuous variable in the field of real numbers. It becomes quantized in potential wells, as with the hydrogen atom that has specific energy levels.

A free particle  can have any energy and emit and a photon of any energy can come out in [Compton scattering](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/comptint.html) or [brehmstrahlung.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung).

So no quantization of motion, as in bound states motion is figurative as the only thing we know are the [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital).